# Python for loop in Django returning random value in dictionary

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, wagtail

I have a Wagtail page displaying the routing link block inside it and I'm adding an icon to the routing link model to display with title in the block on main page. In the main page I'm getting the context for uploaded file field for icon as below:

```
def get_context(self, request):
   context = super().get_context(request)
   routing_links_queryset = self.routing_links
   for link in routing_links_queryset:            
      i_link = link.link_icon
      if i_link:
           try:
              with i_link.icon.open() as file_obj:
                  data = file_obj.read()
                  data = data.decode("utf-8")                          
                  context["iconlink_data"] = data
           except OSError:
                pass
   return context
```

link_icon is field in routing_links model and icon is Filefield in Icon model. Now this is returning the context on the main page but if there are 2 routing link blocks on the main page, it will render the same icon for both.

Do I have to append the context in each iteration? How exactly I could append in this case or any alternative way to do this?

Comment: It's because of this line `context["iconlink_data"] = data`. You should add the icons to a list; such that you can do something like `context["iconlink_data"].append(data)`. Then in your template, you can loop through the list to display all the icons individually.

Comment: That way it will overwrite the value for key again with last iteration value, If I could do something like this: context[str(link)] = data, how will I get the value in template? Currently, I'm loading the context with dict key as <svg height="35" width="35" style="display: inline">{{ iconlink_data|safe }}</svg>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify get_context to add all the icons to a context["links"] dict, then loop through it in the template:

```
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super().get_context(request)
    routing_links_queryset = self.routing_links
    context["links"] = []
    for link in routing_links_queryset: 
        link_dict = {"link_obj": link}
        i_link = link.link_icon
        if i_link:
            try:
                with i_link.icon.open() as file_obj:
                    data = file_obj.read()
                    data = data.decode("utf-8")                          
                    link_dict["iconlink_data"] = data
        context["links"].append(link_dict)
            except OSError:
                pass
    return context
```

in the Django Template it would look something like:

```
{% for link_dict in links %}
   {{ link_dict.link_obj }}
   {{ link_dict.link_obj.link_field }}
   <svg height="35" width="35" style="display: inline">{{ link_dict.iconlink_data|safe }}</svg>
{% endfor %}
```

(Added as an answer for formatting)

Comment: Thanks Ben, I tried this method and now it's showing all icons on all routing link blocks, how can I make association of this list item with the routing link block to show only it's own icon? link_icon is the foreign key field in routing_links model, icon is the field in original Icon model, routing_links has parental key relation with main page, where I want to show the icon in the routing link block and routing link has it's own html file.

Comment: This is how the context of routing links loaded:                           
   context["routing_links"] = [ link for link in routing_links_queryset]   is there a way to connect these 2 lists ?

Comment: @HarpreetSidhu I've updated my answer above to fit your added descriptions.

Comment: still having the same issue, returning all of the icons for all link blocks.

Comment: I've updated the code more to hopefully clarify. You should have "links" in your context, which is a list of dicts. Each dict will look something like: `{"link_obj": link, "iconlink_data": data}`

Comment: I added this to the template: {% if link.link == routing_link %} and boom!! now it's loading the icon for link it belongs to. Thanks a lot @Ben